# CoreDNS Help - Looks Like a Loop

Tags: dns, kubernetes

I've been looking online and I haven't found a solution to this issue yet. I currently have a Kubernetes cluster where I have to have an upstream. Currently, I see the DNS query requests coming in. However, I see the requests coming in with an extra domain name added. The request return with NOERROR. Thus, my pods are failing startup because they can't connect to essential resources.

Here's my CoreDNS config map:

```
.:53 {
  kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
    pods insecure
    upstream 10.14.75.14 10.18.94.231
    fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
  }
  errors
  health
  forward . 10.14.75.14 10.18.94.231 /etc/resolv.conf
  prometheus :9153
  cache 30
  reload
  loadbalance
}
roguenetworks.com:53 {
  forward . 10.14.75.14 10.18.94.231
  cache
  log
}
```

Here are how my logs look right now:

```
10.138.38.31:38787 - [30/May/2019:21:18:53 +0000] 61970 "AAAA IN vault.roguenetworks.com.roguenetworks.com. udp 44 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 141 0.00007525s
10.138.38.31:38787 - [30/May/2019:21:18:53 +0000] 61129 "A IN vault.roguenetworks.com.roguenetworks.com. udp 44 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 141 0.000080292s
10.138.38.31:47592 - [30/May/2019:21:18:53 +0000] 47432 "AAAA IN vault.roguenetworks.com.roguenetworks.com. udp 44 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 141 0.000079604s
10.138.38.31:47592 - [30/May/2019:21:18:53 +0000] 46605 "A IN vault.roguenetworks.com.roguenetworks.com. udp 44 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 141 0.000075072s
10.138.38.31:52411 - [30/May/2019:21:19:01 +0000] 20306 "A IN vault.roguenetworks.com.roguenetworks.com. udp 44 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 141 0.000069465s
10.138.38.31:35466 - [30/May/2019:21:19:08 +0000] 35151 "AAAA IN vault.roguenetworks.com.roguenetworks.com. udp 44 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 141 0.000077839s
10.138.38.31:35466 - [30/May/2019:21:19:08 +0000] 34166 "A IN vault.roguenetworks.com.roguenetworks.com. udp 44 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 141 0.000049698s
```

As you can see, an extra roguenetworks.com is getting added to each query. Anyone has any idea what may be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Searching on internet i found the following information:

https://docs.giantswarm.io/guides/advanced-coredns-configuration/

Regarding networking concepts the básics that define the issue are first that You have a different DNS configuration not that is not useful but that takes more time for conectivity, additionally is if not could it be that something is shutting down the services could it be a malware or an unathorized user, so is better to check Network but security too.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this article and tried to use it to help out but it didn't work for my current configuration.